# How do I restore my saved games on XBox?

Tags: xbox-360

I recently moved, and during the move I packed up my XBox 360, recovered my gamertag on my brother's XBox 360, and played there.  I only now got my own place, and so I unpacked my own XBox.  My brother created a USB storage device on his machine, copied my games over to it, then emailed them to me.

So I've got an `XBox` directory with four files, `Data0000`, `Data0001`, `Data0002`, and `Data0003` on it.  How can I turn this into something my XBox can read?  I tried creating a storage device and overriding the `Data000x` files on it with these, but that doesn't seem to work (it just asks to reformat it when I plug it in to the XBox).

Comment: Did you try this not moving Data0000 and Data0001? Those files are apparently used for system settings and things like that and may be causing problems when you overwrite them on your device. Also, if your devices aren't formatted exactly the same, it's possible it won't work the same either as these files probably have some kind of security on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't copy the files your brother did send to you because of the xbox 360's filesystem. This is why when you plug the usb on the console format it.
You have to ask your brother to give you the original usb key with the save game on it:D!

Answer (score 0):

You need the original USB from the xbox and plug it back into your current xbox go to the memory section and restore

Answer (score 0):

Kreker gave the official correct answer. I do not know if these files will ever work when put on a new USB, however
fatxplorer https://fatxplorer.eaton-works.com/ might be able to explore these files and allow you to extract the saves and copy them over to a new formatted usb. What I do know is the dev of this tool is very helpful, so please check the forums for your situation if it's recoverable (before purchase).

Due to my question required a feature not implemented back then, he sent me a beta version to test and I was able to recover my files from a original Xbox hard disk and memory unit. This beta only worked for a month and now I also have to pay for it to fully function. There is a demo available and maybe you can test if this would be something of use.

Easiest and cheapest would be getting that USB from your brother still. And yes, I would love to suggest a opensource tool, but I dont think "Xplorer360" would work. (it's a free tool, works on real hdd and full dumps)